# Extra black area after exporting image from Google Earth Engine to ArcMap

Tags: google-earth-engine, arcmap

When a .tiff image exported from GEE opened in ArcMap, why the extra black background appears along with the required geometry?

Using this code for exporting to google drive:

```
Export.image.toDrive({image: classified, description: 'GreenLand', region: MH, scale: 10,  });
```

Attaching the screenshot for a better understanding.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell since I cannot access the script, but replacing `image` for `image.clip(MH)` might do the trick. Let me know how that worked.